# Creating objects in a loop Python -- puzzling behavior

Tags: python-3.x, loops, oop, garbage-collection

I have looked at solutions of questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831280/how-python-handles-object-instantiation-in-a-for-loop), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831280/how-python-handles-object-instantiation-in-a-for-loop) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831280/how-python-handles-object-instantiation-in-a-for-loop)) that look similar but aren't. I still can't make sense of what is happening here.

```py
class Page:
    def __init__(self, l = []):
        self.lines = l

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.lines)

class Line:
    def __init__(self, string=None):
        self.str = string

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.str)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
    pages = []
    for row in data:
        page = Page()
        #print(page)
        #print(id(page))
        for x in row:
            line = Line(str(x))
            page.lines.append(line)
        pages.append(page)
print('Pages: ', pages)
```

The answer I expect is

```
Pages: [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]
```

What I get instead is

```
Pages: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

I printed the `page` variable and see it is already populated when the outermost loop is in the second iteration. But how? Shouldn't I get a new empty object?

I am not looking for ways to fix the problem or getting my expected output, I know a few ways. I want to understand why I get this output.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`def __init__(self, l = []):` kinda create global default value of `l`, which you change later (`page.lines` refer to this global array, it's not  recreating on each call).

Slightly better implementation:

```
class Page:
    def __init__(self, l = None):
        self.lines = l if l else []
```

Comment: Ahh! So `self.lines` is simply stores the reference to the global list `l` and creating an object of Page changes this global list each time.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest something like the following instead?

```
def main():
    data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
    pages = []
    for row in data:
        page = Page()
        print(page)
        print(id(page))
        for x in row:
            line = Line(str(x))
            page.append(line)
        pages.append(page)
    print('Pages:', pages)


class Page:
    def __init__(self, lines=None):
        if lines is None:
            lines = []
        if not isinstance(lines, list):
            raise TypeError('argument must by of type list')
        if not all(isinstance(item, Line) for item in lines):
            raise TypeError('list must only contain items of type Line')
        self.__lines = lines

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__!s}({self.__lines!r})'

    def append(self, line):
        if not isinstance(line, Line):
            raise TypeError('argument must be of type Line')
        self.__lines.append(line)


class Line:
    def __init__(self, text=None):
        if text is None:
            text = ''
        if not isinstance(text, str):
            raise TypeError('argument must be of type str')
        self.__text = text

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__!s}({self.__text!r})'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem as [Green_Wizard points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62416434/216356) is that your initializer for your `Page` class is sharing the list between all instances it creates. One way you could fix that is by requiring the caller of the class to always pass in a list for storing your pages. Otherwise, you could do something similar to what is shown in the code up above.